# How does returning a reference to Path from the function's stack work?

Tags: syntax, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

The following snippet is from rust source code for path.rs

```
impl AsRef<Path> for String {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Path {
        Path::new(self)
    }
}
```

It seems to be returning a reference of a newly created `Path` object from the stack frame. How does it bypass Rust's borrow checking rules? A stack object should have a lifetime for the current frame only and returning reference for temporary objects should produce an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The returned reference does not point to some object that is newly created inside of `as_ref()`, but rather to the data of the string that was passed in as an argument.

Let's make the lifetimes in the relevant functions explicit. The prototype

```
fn as_ref(&self) -> &Path
```

can be desugared to

```
fn as_ref(&'a self) -> &'a Path
```

The type of `self` is `&'a String`, a reference to a string with lifetime `'a`.

Inside the function body, `Path::new()` is called. According to the documentation, it is defined like this:

```
pub fn new<S: AsRef<OsStr> + ?Sized>(s: &S) -> &Path
```

Adding the elided lifetime gives

```
pub fn new<S: AsRef<OsStr> + ?Sized>(s: &'a S) -> &'a Path
```

so the newly created `Path` reference will have the same lifetime as the reference we passed in, which is exactly the required lifetime of the return value.